# Как к динамически созданному элементу добавить onclick()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Используя jQuery, я динамически создаю элемент. В данном случае пусть это будет ссылка:

```
createEl: function() {
    if (options.backBtn.enable) {
        var hrefBtn = $('<a/>', {
            class: 'back-link',
            href: '#',
            text: 'Назад'
        });
        $(options.backBtn.element).after(hrefBtn);
        console.log('Just created desctop icon back');
    }
}
```

Как мне к этой ссылке добавить некое действие на `onClick`? Например,  `window.history.back;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `$` сразу же вам вернёт созданный элемент, обёрнутый в jQuery, поэтому можно сразу повесить обработчик:

```
$('<a />').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked!');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

На вопрос уже ответили, но хочу еще сказать вам про 
**Делегирование событий**: cуть в том, что бы вешать событие не на сам элемент, а на его родителя.

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.child', function () {
    /* ваш код */
});
```

**Как это работает?**

- Кликаем по элементу `.child`
- Вызывается событие `click`, на нашем `child` нет обработчика
- **Всплытие** - событие начинает всплывать и переходит к элементу `parent`, который является родителем `child`, на нем уже есть наш
  обработчик. В обработчике проверяется, на какой элемент мы кликнули,
  и если соответствует селектору ( `child`, первый параметр в ф-ции
  `click`), то вызывается обработчик, в контексте `child`;

Это можно организовать и на чистом js

```
parent.onclick = function (e) {
    var target = e.target // без кроссбраузерности, только для примера
    /* допустим проверяем по классу */
    if(target.className == 'child') {
        /* тут можно выполнить, что угодно */
    }
}
```

Можно организовать некую обертку

```
function delegate(parent, child, event, func) {
    var parent = document.querySelector(parent);
    var childs = document.querySelectorAll(child);
    parent.addEventListener(event, function (e) {
        var target = e.target; // плевать на IE
        if(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(childs, target) < 0)
            return; // не наш элемент
        func.call(e.target); 
        // выполнится в контексте target, можно и параметры передать
    }, false);
}
```

**Зачем?**

Теперь, каким бы мыслимым и немыслимым образом вы бы не добавили элемент `child` в `parent`, на `child` будет срабатывать обработчик. Потому что на самом деле он срабатывает на элементе `parent` :)

Comment: Пожалуй, стоит ещё добавить, что сравнение `.className` со строкой `"child"` - не лучшая идея, потому что при наличии у элемента двух классов это будет работать неправильно. Конечно, в вопросе у элемента всего один класс, но для будущих посетителей было бы полезно знать, что правильнее проворачивать такое через `.classList`.

Answer (score -1):

`$('body').on('click','.back-link', function(){console.log('click-click');})`

Comment: Речь в вопросе идет о только что созданном элементе, а не о всех элементах класса `back-link`.